# Break down an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I am trying to break down an array of the size 1x117031 (X array) to an array of size Nx140 (Y array) so I can plot the new array and find out how the plots changed during the cyclic tests (N to be around 1000).

Here is my code:

```
mydata=xlsread('average_4_5');

for i=100:size(mydata)
    X(i-99)=mydata(i,10);
end

for j=1:1000
    Y(j, 1:140)=X(1,((140*j)-140):140*j);
end
```

But I get an error:

> Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

It seems the problem is coming from the `X(1,((140*j)-140):140*j)` and I don't have any idea why this doesn't recognise `j` as being an integer value.

Any thoughts on how I can do this transformation and plot the rows of `Y` to give me a graph with 1000 entries?

Comment: I not sure I followed exactly what you wanted to do, but it sounds like you could very likely drop all your loops and just use the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function.

Comment: @Dan Thank you for your comment. Exactly, I replaced mine now with a reshape function and it works. Thanks for reminding me of that

Comment: It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variables names in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/1714410).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`((140*j)-140)` is `0` when `j` is `1`. The problem is not that `j` is not an integer but that you can't index a matrix with `0`. So the keyword here is not *integer* but *positive*.

However the built-in function [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) should solve this for you.